# Filling fields with dates from a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a df sorted by provinces with info about car accidents from 01/03/2021 to 05/03/2021 (DD/MM/YYYY).

```
  DATE     PROVINCE CAR_ACCIDENTS
1 01/03/21 SANTA                1
2 02/03/21 SANTA                2
3 04/03/21 SANTA                1
4 01/03/21 AREQUIPA             3
5 02/03/21 AREQUIPA             5
6 03/03/21 AREQUIPA             3
7 05/03/21 AREQUIPA             2
```

But as you can see there are some dates that do not appear because they do not record cases on those days. So what I want to get is something like this, where the missing days are filled in with a 0.

```
  DATE     PROVINCE CAR_ACCIDENTS
 1 01/03/21 SANTA                1
 2 02/03/21 SANTA                2
 3 03/03/21 SANTA                0
 4 04/03/21 SANTA                1
 5 05/03/21 SANTA                0
 6 01/03/21 AREQUIPA             3
 7 02/03/21 AREQUIPA             5
 8 03/03/21 AREQUIPA             3
 9 04/03/21 AREQUIPA             0
10 05/03/21 AREQUIPA             2
```

I had tried creating a df with all the dates I want and then doing a `full_join` with the previous one, but didn't get the result I'm looking for.

```
begin=as.Date("01/03/2021")
final=as.Date("05/03/2021")
dates=data.frame(as.Date(beign:final))
names(dates)[1]="DATE"

library(dplyr)
try1<-df%>%
  group_by(PROVINCES)%>%
  full_join(dates,by="DATE")
```

The `dput` of the `df` is:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(DATE = c("01/03/21", "02/03/21", "04/03/21", "01/03/21", 
"02/03/21", "03/03/21", "05/03/21"), PROVINCE = c("SANTA", "SANTA", 
"SANTA", "AREQUIPA", "AREQUIPA", "AREQUIPA", "AREQUIPA"), CAR_ACCIDENTS = c(1, 
2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(DATE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), PROVINCE = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), CAR_ACCIDENTS = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: I had edited the question to add it @andrew_reece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code with a slight modification:

```
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(DATE = dmy(DATE)) %>%
  group_by(PROVINCE) %>%
  complete(DATE = full_seq(DATE, 1), fill = list(CAR_ACCIDENTS = 0))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   PROVINCE [2]
  PROVINCE DATE       CAR_ACCIDENTS
  <chr>    <date>             <dbl>
1 AREQUIPA 2021-03-01             3
2 AREQUIPA 2021-03-02             5
3 AREQUIPA 2021-03-03             3
4 AREQUIPA 2021-03-04             0
5 AREQUIPA 2021-03-05             2
6 SANTA    2021-03-01             1
7 SANTA    2021-03-02             2
8 SANTA    2021-03-03             0
9 SANTA    2021-03-04             1
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(DATE = c("01/03/21", "02/03/21", "04/03/21", "01/03/21", 
"02/03/21", "03/03/21", "05/03/21"), PROVINCE = c("SANTA", "SANTA", 
"SANTA", "AREQUIPA", "AREQUIPA", "AREQUIPA", "AREQUIPA"), CAR_ACCIDENTS = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: For some reason when I tried with another similar df the `fill = list(CAR_ACCIDENTS = 0)` didn't fill the column with 0 but with NAs. Do you know why it could be?

Comment: It's weird! can you share a piece of that data by `dput(head(data))`?

Answer (score 1):

I have followed @Anoushiravan R's answer so that I can choose the start and end dates my way.

```
begin=as.Date("2021-03-01")
final=as.Date("2021-03-05")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

df%>%
group_by(PROVINCE)%>%
complete(DATE= seq.Date(min(begin),
max(final), 
by = "day")) %>%
complete(fill=list(CAR_ACCIDENTS=0))
```

In his, the start and end dates are kept as they are in the data frame and only the ones in between are filled in.

For the given example I think his answer is correct, but for a more complex case, this may be helpful.